# Search functionality in pdfrenderer

Tags: java, swing, pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the pdfpage content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598258/how-to-get-the-pdfpage-content)

I am using pdfrenderer to view my pdf file in swing.In this pdfviewer i need a search functionality same as it is like in adobe reader search(showing the pages link and clicking on the link should go to that page and highlight the search word).How can i achieve this in swing.Is there any samples to do like this.Or do i need to use any other libraries.

Thank You.

Comment: @StanislavL Thank You for giving the reply.With that link i am able to perform the search and able to display the Matches count.But i need to display the page links also.When i click on the link it should go to that page and show the match words with highlight(same as in adobe reader search).

Comment: Then show your current code. Post SSCCE here.